# Add Text Box to Word Document Table Through a VBA Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, report, reporting

The situation is the following:

I am using SQL Server Reporting Service to produce a report that is exported to Word 2010.  The report itself comes out as a set of nested tables.  I need to be able to reach in to one of these inner tables and add a Text Box to a specific cell in the table.

I need to do this in a way that I can do it I a loop, to loop through all of the rows in the specific table.  The table can have *n* rows, and this cell needs to be modified in each of them.  The problem, therefore is twofold.  I need to be able to index into the correct table and get a pointer to the specific cell, and then I need to modify the contents of the cell to have a single text box control in it.   It is my understanding that you use the shapes collection to add the text box itself, but I don't know how to get a reference to the specific cell of the specific table, and find the shapes collection that is associated with it.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

I am using this code to try and iterate the tables in the document, but there is no "HasTable" property, just one for "HasChart" and "HasSmartArt"

```
Dim Shp As Shape
For Each Shp In ThisDocument.InlineShapes 
    If Shp.HasTable Then 
        MsgBox "Found Table" 
    End If 
Next Shp
```

This code will add a text box but I don't see how to get this to be in the right column of the table I am working with, nor does this give me a way t index through all of the rows in the table adding the text box:

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=lLeft, 
    Top:=6, _
    Width:=72, _
    Height:=12
```

I have tried the following and it doesn't seem to help:

> Dim tbl As Word.Table  For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
>
> ```
>     tbl.Columns.Select
>
>
>     If tbl.Tables.Count > 0 Then
>       tbl.Tables(1).Select
>
>           ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
>           Left:=tbl.Tables(1).Columns.Borders.DistanceFromLeft, _
>           Top:=tbl.Tables(1).Columns.Borders.DistanceFromTop, _
>           Width:=72, _
>           Height:=12
>
>     End If
> Next tbl
> ```

This will add the text box, but it doesn't put it in the right cell.

The Visual Tree in XAML is a hierarchical data structure that contains all the visual elements of a XAML page.  You can walk it recursively looking for specific nodes, and then modify the content of the given node once you find that.  That is what I am trying to do here, but I am not seeing that kind of structure

Comment: what have you tried so far?  I'm prtty sure that Tables are a member of the document's `InlineShapes` collection. Iterate that collection checking for whether each shape's `.HasTable = True` property, and then you should be able to work with the table that way.

Comment: Thanks!  I've tried various ways of trying to index through the ActiveDocument.Shapes collection and the ThisDocument.Tables collection. I hadn't tried the InlineShapes, though.  That seems to get me some of the shapes, but there isn't a HasTable property to the Shape object.  This is  the code I used to test that:           [quote] Dim Shp As Shape
    For Each Shp In ThisDocument.InlineShapes
        If Shp.HasTable Then
            MsgBox "Found Table"
        End If
    Next Shp [/quote] There is now "HasTable" property, just one for "HasChart" and "HasSmartArt"

Comment: OK give me a minute... I am mostly working in PowerPoint so it may be a little different.  I'll follow-up...

Comment: Just a little more info, this code will add a text box: [code]ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=lLeft, _
    Top:=6, Width:=72, Height:=12 [/code], but I don't see how to get this to be in the right column of the table I am working with, nor does this give me a way t index through all of the rows in the table adding the text box. I am coming from a C#/XAML background. Is there anything like a Visual Tree in Word?

Comment: Can you please put **code** in the question, not in the comments where it is frankly impossible to read...

Comment: OK, there is a `Tables` collection in Word.  `For each tbl in ActiveDocument.Tables...`

Comment: Not sure what a visual tree is, do you mean like a tree view where you can inspect the local/instantiated variables/objects and their respective properties?  Yes, the "Locals" window can be enabled from View menu in the VBE.

Comment: OK you have a good start. I am looking at this too and have some other information that we can try, give me a few minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

heavily modified from code found here:

http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/11055-word-vba-add-textboxs-table-cells.html

Try this, may require some slight tweaking for your specific use but this will add a textbox relative to any cell in a table, and set its anchor to the table.

Untested revision should look for multiple placeholders (specify placeholder text in `strText` variable) and add textbox with the appropriate cell for each, in each table.

```
Option Explicit
Sub AddTextBoxToTableCell()
Dim tbl As Table
Dim tblRow As Row
Dim t As Integer
Dim bkmark As String
Dim tblCell As Cell
Dim clTop As Long
Dim clLeft As Long
Dim tbWidth As Single
Dim tbHeight As Single
Dim strText as String


'## Specify dimensions of textbox:
    tbWidth = 72
    tbHeight = 10

'## Specify the placeholder text
    strText = "[placeholder for textbox]"

'## Iterate the tables
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables

    t = t + 1


    '## Define the cell we want to use (modify as needed)
    For r = 1 to tbl.Rows.Count
        For c = 1 to tbl.Columns.Count
            If tbl.Cell(r,c).Range.Text = strText then
               '## Construct a string to use as a Bookmark
                bkmark = "table_" & t & "_Row" & r & "_Col" & c
                Set tblCell = tbl.Cell(r, c)


                '## Get the position of the cell
                clLeft = GetCellAbsoluteLeft(tblCell)
                clTop = tblCell.Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)

                '## Add a bookmark if it does not already exist
                If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(bkmark) Then
                    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bkmark).Delete
                End If

                '## Add/Update the bookmark location
                ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "table_" & t, tblCell.Range

                '## Add a textbox to your table:
                ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                    clLeft, clTop, tbWidth, tbHeight, _
                    Anchor:=ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bkmark).Range
            End If
        Next
    Next


Next


End Sub

Function GetCellAbsoluteLeft(cl As Cell) As Long
'## Custom function to return the absolute left position in points, of a table cell
Dim col As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim ret As Long

ret = cl.Range.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)

col = cl.Range.Information(wdStartOfRangeColumnNumber)

c = 1

'## Add up the column widths with the position wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage
Do
    ret = ret + cl.Row.Cells(c).Width
    c = c + 1
Loop While Not c >= col

'## Return the value:
GetCellAbsoluteLeft = ret

End Function
```

Comment: That gets me pointed in the right direction.  I am still having to sort through the tables looking for a string that is a placeholder, but I think this will put the text box where I need it when I find the right cell.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Is there only one placeholder in each table?

Comment: Modified to look for a single placeholder text in each table.

Comment: And I am basically there now.  Victory of Man over Machine :)  Again, thanks for the help.  I've been going around in circles on that for more than a day/

Comment: There are n placeholders in the table. The particular report I am working on only has one, but in production it could be showing any number of rows, each with their own placeholder.

Comment: OK well if this has helped, do consider accepting the answer or upvoting it.  Cheers.